# Why was my proposed title rejected?

Tags: support, edits, title

I came across a post while reviewing edits where the post could use a lot of cleanup. So I did, including modifying the title to read:

> How do I debounce clicks on my marker?

When I tried to save the edit, Stack Overflow wouldn't let me. It said it wouldn't accept my title and suggested I read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask:

[image]

I found nothing informative there which would explain why the edit was not being accepted.

Lacking any insight as to what I'd done wrong, I rewrote the title so that instead read:

> How can clicks on my marker be debounced?

That edit was accepted.

I don't see why one was accepted and one was not. Researching what restrictions exist for titles, I didn't find anything that would apply. I was over the 15-character minimum, I didn't have any prohibited words (indeed, the accepted title had almost identical words…the only word difference was that I replaced "do" with "can", and added the word "be"), and the title wasn't identical to any others.

Would someone please explain to me what was wrong with the first version of the title I'd tried?

Comment: I believe the _"How do I"_ is the culprit.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I believe you're mistaken. There are plenty of posts, including at least a half-dozen from the last couple of hours, with "How do I" in the title.

Comment: I am not sure if all the filters are documented. I just know about a few wordings which are usually rejected in titles.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: that's fine, but "how do I" clearly is not one of those wordings. There are plenty of counter-examples to prove that.

Comment: This seems to be well-written and researched. It's not clear to me why it's being downvoted. I'm assuming you're hitting some filters, too, but that doesn't seem to be a reason to downvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From some brief testing, it looks like the title filter blocks the word "my" for some reason unless the title is at least 40 characters long, which your second one barely meets.

[This is a very long-standing annoyance.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so)

Comment: Well, I guess I can take solace in the fact that at least I'm not the only person annoyed by the title filter rules (I have even run into at least one situation where not being able to edit the title to the exact text of another one was a problem...I was just trying to fix a misspelling in someone else's post, which meant that there's a good chance the misspelling was actually intentional, because of these very rules!)